# Intern functional test - iterating on set of items

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, intern

This seems trivial, but I'm attempting to set up a functional test in Intern to check the inner text of a set of span elements in my page all with the same CSS class, but I can't seem to be able to isolate the text within the span. Here is my code:

```
        'Span check': function () {
            return this.remote
                .findAllByClassName('mySpanClass')
                .then(function (elems) {                    
                    assert.strictEqual(elems[0].innerHTML(),'Span Text');
                 })
        }
```

I've run separate tests to verify that the spans are being found... the findAllByClassName function returns an array of two Objects.

Anyone done anything like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`getVisibleText()`](http://theintern.github.io/leadfoot/Command.html#getVisibleText) instead:

> Gets the visible text within the element. elements are converted
>   to line breaks in the returned text, and whitespace is normalised per
>   the usual XML/HTML whitespace normalisation rules.

```
return this.remote
    .findByCssSelector('.mySpanClass')
    .getVisibleText()
    .then(function (text) {                    
        assert.strictEqual(text, 'Span Text');
     });
```

This would work for a single element.

If you want to check the text of each span, use:

```
return this.remote
    .findAllByCssSelector('.mySpanClass')
    .getVisibleText()
    .then(function (texts) {                    
        assert.strictEqual(texts, ['Span1 Text', 'Span2 Text']);
     });
```

Comment: Tried this as well, still doesn't quite seem to work: expected { Object (cancel, then) } to equal 'Span Text'

Comment: @emroc are you sure you have `then()` after the `getVisibleText()` as I have in the answer? Thanks.

Comment: Should getVisibleText be used for the result of a 'getAll'? I assumed because we are returning an array, this would not be the correct approach.

Comment: @emroc well, I've provided you with a `get...()` (single element) based approach, since this would get you the first element by class name - which is what you were getting with `getAll...()` plus `elems[0]`. Try running exactly what I've provided. Thanks.

Comment: Understood, your code works well in that case. What I'm hoping to do though is iterate over all the span elements. I'm simply working with the first one alone to try to understand the correct syntax.

Comment: @emroc good, I've updated the answer with an example using `findAll..()`.

Comment: Thanks, got it working now. GetVisibleText was returning blank because the span is set to 'display: none'.